# Vimrc keymapping with an argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

I'm using Vim.rails and trying to customize the configuration:

```
:Rcontroller name
```

This command will open up the name_controller file in Rails.

How could I map this command to a key such that I can specify whatever "name" controller to open? In other words, I would need to pass in an argument...

I'd like to use the mapping:

```
<leader>name
```

to run :Rcontroller name with a . Or

```
<leader>othername
```

to run :Rcontroller othername with a .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible method that I can think of from my (limited) understanding of Vim. However, your binding will need to be predefined as something (i.e. you won't be able to just type the controller name with `<leader>`).

```
nnoremap <leader>R :Rcontroller<space>
```

When you press `<leader>R`, the command line will read `:Rcontroller []`, where `[]` is the current cursor. Then you should be able to easily type in whatever argument you'd like.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly.   Didn't think of not ending it with a <CR>. Thanks a ton